# Failed to install Go extension in Visual Studio Code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

When I try to install the Go Extension in my Visual Studio Code, and I got these error messages as below.
Am I missing something here?

```
 gocode
  gopkgs
  go-outline
  go-symbols
  guru
  gorename
  godef
  goreturns
  golint
  dlv

Installing github.com/nsf/gocode FAILED
Installing github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/cmd/gopkgs FAILED
Installing github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline FAILED
Installing github.com/acroca/go-symbols FAILED
Installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru FAILED
Installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename FAILED
Installing github.com/rogpeppe/godef FAILED
Installing github.com/sqs/goreturns FAILED
Installing github.com/golang/lint/golint FAILED
Installing github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv FAILED

10 tools failed to install.

gocode:
Error: Command failed: /usr/local/go/bin/go get -u -v github.com/nsf/gocode
package github.com/nsf/gocode: cannot download, /home/bitnumbers/go is a GOROOT, not a GOPATH. For more details see: 'go help gopath'
package github.com/nsf/gocode: cannot download, /home/bitnumbers/go is a GOROOT, not a GOPATH. For more details see: 'go help gopath'
```

Please advice.

Comment: Please provide additional output of `echo $GOROOT` and `echo $GOPATH`

Comment: @IsaacCarolWeisberg - I just ran the command on my local machine terminal, the result is empty. I am new to Go. Please advice

Comment: Try to run the commands inside src folder from terminal of vscode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have pointed out in your comment, on your system
`echo $GOPATH` and `echo $GOROOT` produce empty output. This indicates an incomplete installation of `go`. Now, assuming you have installed the `go` toolchain via the downloads on the website or better yet, `gvm`, the all there is left to do is make the environment persist the changes across terminal sessions.

Adding

```
export GOPATH=*your path to GOPATH*
export GOROOT=*path to your go installation*
```

to your `~/.bashrc`, restarting terminal session, restarting VSCode and reattempting to install the tools should do the trick.

**Further reading**:

https://golang.org/doc/install#install

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH

https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH

Comment: @Issac . Thank you. In-fact, I found one video on YouTube is really helpful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGq6CPff2EY

Comment: "This indicates an incomplete installation of go" not true. [As of Go 1.9 GOROOT is no longer required](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#goroot) (before that it defaulted to /usr/local/go), and [GOPATH defaults to $HOME/go](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH).

Comment: If you receive a `Error: Command failed go get...` even though you set the paths in bashrc, you might want to check if there is a problem with git, since these packages are downloaded via git. 

It also helped to manually run one command after another, instead of automatically running them all at once

Answer (score 0):

I removed all old Visual Studio Code in mac. I installed latest Visual studio code and it solved the issue.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac

This is my .bashrc and .bash_profile setting:

```
export GOPATH=/Users/user/work
export GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.15.7/libexec
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```